# How do i make the top frame cover the whole horizontal space?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do i make the top frame cover the whole horizontal space
Just a small piece of code
Although i have used proper size still its *not covering the whole area*

[image]

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Customer Billing System")
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.root.config(background="powder blue")

        ABC=Frame(self.root,bg="powder blue",bd=20,relief=RIDGE)
        ABC.grid()
        ABC1 = Frame(ABC,bd=14,width=1350,height=100,padx=10,relief=RIDGE,bg="black")
        ABC1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky=W)

        ABC2 = Frame(ABC,bd=14,width=450,height=488,padx=10,relief=RIDGE,bg="cadet blue")
        ABC2.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.lblTitle = Label(ABC1,textvariable=Date1,font=('arial',30,'bold'),pady=9,bd=5,bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.lblTitle = Label(ABC1,text="Customer Billing System",font=('arial',30,'bold'),pady=9,bd=5,bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.lblTitle = Label(ABC1,textvariable=Time1,font=('arial',30,'bold'),pady=9,bd=5,bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=0,column=2)
```

Comment: I suggest to use `pack()` for the frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to set the height or width of a Frame, because Frames are designed to adjust to the size of what you pack into them so those sizes are almost immediately overwritten. Instead, use the sticky argument to tell the Frame to use the size of it's container instead. In your case, stick to the east and west sides:

```
ABC1 = Frame(ABC,bd=14,padx=10,relief=RIDGE,bg="black")
ABC1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,sticky=E+W)
ABC1.columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # set column 1 (the middle one) to consume extra space.
```

Comment: Thanks it helped the frame covered the remaining space but the text is still on one side didnt spread in the frame @Novel

Comment: @JustinPaul To spread the elements of the frame you need to set which columns get to consume the extra space using columnconfigure. I'll add an example.